# Print Query Result in Console - Robot Framework

Tags: python, sql, automation, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework in automations. Now I'm adding SQL Server scripts.

In order to facilitate, I would like to make a print of my query (select) to display in the console.

How do I do?

I tried with the following way, but without success:

```
Log    SELECT *FROM TABLEX;
```

and

```
Log To Console    SELECT *FROM TABLEX;
```

The latter prints to the console, but the query sent, in this case, select *from TABLEX.

Also, can I print in the same code using python? Or should the file be .py instead of .robot?

And finaly, can I not keep generating logs after running the tests?

Awaiting.

Thank you!

Comment: You just want to print the string "SELECT *FROM TABLEX;" but it does not work ?

Comment: This! I want to print the result of the query.
Returns that it was done successfully, but the result of my select is not displayed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run a keyword that performs the query. You can capture that result and then log it.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result}=  Query  SELECT * FROM TABLEX;
    log  ${result}
```